# SQL Server Show table when hovering over a keyword

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a before and after query which I'm currently looking at this is filled with Ambiguous Column Name Errors.

I'd like to be able to hover over certain columns in the query in the before query and see which table this was mapped to. When hovering at the moment, all I see is

```
column k(datatype, null)
```

Is there a way to achieve this on SQL Server Management 2012? I'd be happy with a third party plug in if there possible to be installed.

As an example,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE column1 = "stack"
```

In the above example, I'd want to hover over "column1" and see it reference to "Table1" somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to effectively accomplish this by using a `table alias` on the column declarations in: `SELECT`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, etc... clauses.  Assuming the rest of my answer is not helpful for you, I have heard really good things about [SQL Prompt from RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/).

Assuming a simple `SELECT` statement like below you can fairly easily identify what table a column belongs to.  (You should be able to include `AS` in between the `table name` and it's `alias`, I just typically don't).

```
SELECT CP.ClientID,
FAIFN.FaxNumber,
IFax.VendorJobNumber,
IFax.CreateDateTime
FROM ClientProgram CP
    INNER JOIN FaxAccountInboundFaxNumber FAIFN
        ON CP.Id = FAIFN.ClientProgramID
    INNER JOIN InboundFax IFax
        ON IFax.FaxAccountInboundFaxNumberID = FAIFN.ID
WHERE CP.ClientId = @ClientID
```

There is a smaller added benefit for more complicated queries like it sounds like you are working with.  I am able to hover over `table alias` to identify what `table` the `alias` is referencing, and thus what `table` that `column` belongs to. (You can't tell but my mouse was hovering over the `FAIFN` in the `SELECT`)

[image: Hover Over Table Alias for Alias Definition/Source]

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: SQL Prompt done the trick. I installed the free version and this showed what I needed. Thank you for the recommendation.